# WorldWind: 3D-Objects - Sphere for Moon, how?

Tags: java, 3d, jogl, worldwind

I asked this question in an Nasa WorldWind forum but haven't got a reply yet http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=24428

So, perhaps you could help me :).

> I'm still playing around with WWJ and what you posted here http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=24318 THX!
>   currently I'm trying to add different layers, so that I can add several polylines and can clear them, so that I can "let them grow in realtime".
>
> but my aim is still to implement at least basic represantations of moon and other celestial bodies and the spacecraft.
>   I want to use WWJ for a lunar mission and I'm simulating a n-body problem and I would like to have representations of all bodies.
>   it doesn't matter when there are just spheres, but they have to be at least the size and te position of the body simulated.
>
> how can I chieve this? I couldn't find this in the wiki.
>   the uber-thing would be to use WW's moon model and place it accordingly, but just a sphere painted grey would be okay :).
>
> (that's why I asked for a solar view in another thread :))

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if you already know about these, I've never used WWJ myself -- though I may have to play with it a bit when I get home tonight.

Sun has a page on its website ([link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/worldwind/)) about getting started using WorldWind in your apps.  And the WorldWind people have [a wiki](http://worldwindcentral.com/wiki/) that contains [a developer FAQ](http://worldwindcentral.com/wiki/WWJava_Dev_FAQ), among other things.

Comment: Hi, did you play with it? :)
unfortunally I learn such things by tutorials and testing, and I don't understand stuff by the documentary with almost no examples in it. Their wiki isn't specific enough, at least for my taste.

So you could really help me :)